# Scrolling whole Image from UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uiimage

I have a `UICollectionView` with `UIImage` and when i tap on the Cell it´s comes a whole `UIImage`. I want to Slider Right or Left on the whole Image then show the next `UIImage` from the `UICollectionView` like a Photo Gallery. How can i make that ? Thanks for Help.

[UICollectionView and Whole UIImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHSEi.png)

Comment: This is not remotely related to UICollectionView.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UIScrollView for that, large enough to carry 3 images, the current one, the previous one and the next one. The largest is in the middle. The scrollview scrolls horizontally. Then you react on scrolling (and gestures) and when the user scrolls to right or left then you scroll your scrollview to the middle again and realign the 3 images by discarding one and adding a new one dependig on the direction the user scrolled.

Comment: That hears good have you a code example for me, there i can see that?

Comment: Well, no. I did that long ago in Obj-C but don't have access to the customer's code base any more. Altough the principle is simple and does work actually, there is some coding involved.

Comment: There is one catch that you should be aware of. When you scroll your UIScrollview programatically then the scroll view delegate methods are called anyway, regardless whether you did the scrolling or the user did so. When you are not aware of this then you could easily end up in an endless loop.

Comment: Oke Thanks i try it with the 3 image. I have the current image but how i get the previous and the next image of the uicollectionview ?

Comment: That depends on your application's business logic of course. Your collection view gets that information from its datasource somehow. I guess it is stored in some array or so. You will have to pass this array to your "full screen view" and go from there. You could apply some datasource pattern of course - I would even recommend that. Create your own "ThreeScrollView", a protocol with mehtods like `numberOfImages -> Int` and `imageForIndex(index: Int) -> UIImage` and let the view controller implement it. That would make it reusable for you. You may even want to publish it.